# weighted average price without cummax

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the weighted average of the below.

```
a = {'Price': [10, 15, 5, 25, 30], 'Total': [10000, 12000, 15000, 14000, 0],
     'Previous Quarter': [0, 10000, 12000, 15000, 14000]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
```

I am using the formula below to do it

```
a['Change'] = a['Total'] - a['Previous Quarter']
a['Amount'] = a['Price']*a['Change']
a['Cum Sum Amount'] = np.cumsum(a['Amount'])
a['WAP'] = (a['Cum Sum Amount'] / a['Total']).cummax()
```

I am using cummax as the weighted average price can not reduce if the total reduces. This works well, however if the total increases but the price decreases the weighted average price should decrease but because of cummax it is unable to.

Is there a way so could see something like the below:

```
a['Change'] = a['Total'] - a['Previous Quarter']
a['Amount'] = a['Price']*a['Change']
a['Cum Sum Amount'] = np.cumsum(a['Amount'])
a['WAP'] = [10, 10.83, 10.00, 10.00, 0]
```

Comment: "I am using cummax as the weighted average price can not reduce if the total reduces. " what do you mean? Are you implying that one of your constraints is that you cannot go below the inception price whatever the WAP's value is? or something else?

Comment: if you take the 3rd number in a['wap'] how i want it, you see that it reduces to 10 from 10.83. This is correct however cummax would keep the value at 10.83. However without using cummax the 4th number also 10 would reduce because the total decreases. However, in reality this does not happen. so i need it to say if total decreases then cummax, however if total increases then not cummax

Answer (score 0):

The weighted average price is just revenue / volume. Break the quarterly revenue and volume into their own columns, and then divide the cumsums (this assumes rows are sorted ascending by quarter):

```
a = {'Price': [10, 15, 5, 25, 30], 'Total': [10000, 12000, 15000, 14000, 0],
     'Previous Quarter': [0, 10000, 12000, 15000, 14000]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)

a["quarter_volume"] = a["Total"] - a["Previous Quarter"]
a["quarter_revenue"] = a["Price"] * a["quarter_volume"]
a["quarter_revenue"].cumsum() / a["quarter_volume"].cumsum()
```

Comment: except using this as the total reduces the weighted average decreases. I m trying to avoid this

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. If there are negative sales then the weighted average *should* decrease.